# jenkins throws exception when archiving artifacts

Tags: jenkins

all,
The jenkins threw an exception when archiving artifacts after finished compiling.
Here goes the error message:

```
     Archiving artifacts
12:35:16  ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver aborted due to exception
12:35:16  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
12:35:16    at java.io.File.setLastModified(File.java:1344)
12:35:16    at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2080)
12:35:16    at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2000)
12:35:16    at jenkins.model.StandardArtifactManager.archive(StandardArtifactManager.java:57)
12:35:16    at hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver.perform(ArtifactArchiver.java:140)
12:35:16    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
12:35:16    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
12:35:16    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
12:35:16    at hu2:35:16    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:706)
12:35:16    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1703)
12:35:16    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)
12:35:16    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
12:35:16    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)  dson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1030)
1
```

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by having an artifact larger than 8GB.

See Jenkins bug report [JENKINS-10629](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10629).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've remove this archive action in my jenkins configuration and upload my artifact to FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Do your artifacts generate weird characters like spaces +-._ etc? Try removing them and things should work normally.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, I have solve this problem. This issue took place due to time in slave node machine is later than time in master node machine

Answer (score 0):

If the name of any of the files to be archived is too long, like if it has so many characters, then also this problem can arise.